# What are valid characters for a DNS Zone file and how can I sanitize user input?

Tags: c#, dns, bind

I'm working on an interface to allow our clients to update their DNS on their own.

I have 2 questions:

1. What constitutes valid a valid host and target records? (A, CNAME, MX, TXT) i.e. if the user enters ........ for the host and target the DNS server won't like that.
2. Is there a regex I can use to sanitize user input?

BTW it is BIND9 DNS and C# web app.

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: Re sanitizing user input - check out this article: http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/1/29/ddd-and-rule-driven-ui-validation-in-net.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain name *labels* can technically contain any octet value, but *usually* they only contain alphanumerics and the hyphen and underscore characters.

This comes from recommendations in section 2.3.1 of [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt):

> The labels must follow the rules for
>   ARPANET host names.  They must start
>   with a letter, end with a letter or
>   digit, and have as interior characters
>   only letters, digits, and hyphen. 
>   There are also some restrictions on
>   the length.  Labels must be 63
>   characters or less.

The underscore character is a more recent addition, typically used in the label portion of `SRV` records.

You could also permit the "`.`" character if you're going to let users create their own subdomains.

The *values* that are possible are:

- `A` record - must be a dotted-quad IP address
- `CNAME` record - must be some other legal label
- `MX` record - 16-bit integer priority field, and a legal hostname.  NB: some people put in labels which themselves point only to a `CNAME` record.  This is frowned upon.
- `TXT` record - anything you like!

Note that in every case, if you do allow any of the characters not in the normal set they would need to be escaped if they're being stored in a BIND format zone file.

Comment: The rule in RFC 1035 has been updated by RFC 1123. Starting with a digit is now perfectly normal.

Comment: Certain characters need to be quoted inside the value of a TXT record...

Comment: @JohnHascall only in master file format - the RDATA itself can contain anything

Comment: Correct.  The question was about the file format, not the wire-format.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that even '.' and ascii NUL acharacters are valid in labels. Applications requiring support for this would normally need to employ an escaping mechanism such as used by bind.

Answer (score 1):

The answer used to be easy, but not anymore.

You can use almost any Unicode characters, but they should go thru a normalization, and 
encoding process.

See RFC 3490 (IDNA), RFC 3454 (Stringprep), RFC 3491 (Nameprep), RFC 3492 (Punycode)

Or go with Wikipedia for the big picture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget AAAA, the IPv6 addresses (remember, only two years left before we run out of IPv4 addresses...).

For the legal names, read RFC 1123, section 2.1. **domain** names can be **anything**, **host** names have a much stricter syntax (see RFC 1123).

Comment: we can still get ipv4 addresses

Answer (score -1):

apart from suggestions above, if anyone still faces issue with importing zone files from godaddy to route53, remove the comments. it took me few hours to figure out that comments written as `;comment line here` were causing route 53 system to not parse the zone file properly.